# Why are strap-on boosters more often attached radially in Eastern-European/Asian rockets, and bilaterally in Western-European/American rockets?

Tags: design, booster

While comparing launch vehicles with strap on boosters, it appears to me that the majority of Eastern-European/Asian vehicles arrange the boosters radially, but the Western-European/American vehicles are more likely to employ a pair arranged bilaterally.  Here are some examples:

Radial boosters

[image]

- Soviet/Russian

  - R-7 (Sputnik, Vostok, Soyuz, etc.)
  - Proton
- Japanese

  - N-II
  - H-IIB
- Chinese

  - Long March
- American

  - Delta II/III

Bilateral boosters

[image]

- American

  - Atlas (most)
  - Delta IV
  - Shuttle
  - Falcon Heavy
  - SLS
- ESA

  - Ariane (most)
- Japanese

  - H-II/H-IIA
- Soviet

  - Energia (2 pairs arranged bilaterally)

I understand that vehicles launched from Baikonur needed all components to fit on trains, thus limiting the diameter of the core segment.  Perhaps this created need for more boosters?

Are there other reasons this geographic trend exists?  Different launch needs?  Design ethos?

Or am I wrong that this trend even exists?

Note that I'm not asking which arrangement is better.

(images from wikipedia)

Comment: I deny the premise. Proton doesn't use strap-on boosters; those are propellant tanks permanently attached to the core. Atlas V uses a variable number of boosters attached irregularly-radially, from 1 (411/511 configurations) to 5 (551 configuration). Delta IV Medium uses 2-4 boosters. I'm not sure what you're referring to as Zond; the Zond spacecraft were launched on Soyuz and Proton boosters.

Comment: Most of the examples you cite have 2 boosters, where bilaterally and radially are actually the same thing.